# How to create a custom form component by extending BaseInput in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to create a custom form input component in ionic2, by extending `BaseInput`. But it doesn't rendered, and I can't find it on the DOM.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, Optional, Renderer, 
ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { Config, Form, Item } from "ionic-angular";
import { BaseInput } from "ionic-angular/util/base-input";
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-checkbox',
  template:
  '<p>aaaaa</p>',
  host: {
    '[class.checkbox-disabled]': '_disabled'
  },
  providers: [ { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: MyCheckboxComponent, multi: true } ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class MyCheckboxComponent extends BaseInput<any> implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(form: Form, config: Config, elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer, @Optional() item: Item) {
    super(config, elementRef, renderer, 'my-checkbox', [], form, item, null);
  }

}
```

The code is copy from `src/component/checkbox/checkbox.ts` and make a little changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My component did not get render within `<ion-item>` parent element. I fixed it by adding `item-content` directive

`<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Label</ion-label>
  <my-checkbox item-content></my-checkbox>
</ion-item>`